# Differentiate between Table Views

Tags: xcode, ios5, uistoryboard

I have three table views inside a view controller (going to show/hide table views to display a list of options in different contexts)

Just wondering what the best way is to distinguish between different table views that are using the same delegate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three separate instance variables in your view controller to store the table views. Then in the delegate methods you can do something like this:

```
if (tableView == myFirstTableView) {
    // Do whatever you need for table view 1.
} else if (tableView == mySecondTableView) {
    // Do whatever you need for table view 2.
}
```

Comment: Awesome, straightforward enough. Thanks. I have to wait 12 more minutes to give you a nice green check mark, though.